# Android - Maps API - Check the current address location type

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, google-places-api

I was wondering as to whether it is possible to get the current location type based on the address. The implementation is that using GPS I will be able to get the address of the current location (similar to dropping pins on Maps and getting the address).

What I would like to know is whether based on the address, can I get the type of the location for example whether it is a movie theater, hospital, a restaurant, shopping mall, etc.

Has anyone tried to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can use the [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/) to get the place_id. This is a unique identifer that can be used with other Google APIs, like the [Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/details). This gives more information (name, ratings, etc).

Comment: Ok. Hence by combining both the Geocoding API and the Places API, the nature of the current address can be obtained by using the place_id. I have not yet tried it, but I will give this a try and update.